# How should a json-schema (draft7) implementation resolve `$ref`s defined in unknown keywords?

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

JSON-Schema-Test-Suite defines schemas such as this, and I assume they are valid:

```
{
    "tilda~field": {"type": "integer"},
    "slash/field": {"type": "integer"},
    "percent%field": {"type": "integer"},
    "properties": {
        "tilda": {"$ref": "#/tilda~0field"},
        "slash": {"$ref": "#/slash~1field"},
        "percent": {"$ref": "#/percent%25field"}
    }
}
```

Take this example below:

```
{
    "$id": "http://example.com/root.json",
    "definitions": {
        "A": { "type": "integer" }
    },
    "properties": {
        "$id": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "attributes": {
            "$ref": "#/tilda~0field/slash~1field/$id"
        }
    },
    "tilda~field": {
        "$id": "t/inner.json",
        "slash/field": {
            "$id": {
                "$id": "test/b",
                "$ref": "document.json"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which of the following is the `$ref` at `#/tilda~0field/slash~1field/$id/$ref` resolved to?

- http://example.com/root.json/document.json
- http://example.com/t/document.json
- http://example.com/t/test/document.json

Which of the `$id`s in `#/tilda~0field` must be considered as baseURI for the `$ref` in question and why.

Answer (score 3):

`$ref`s are *not* resolved within unknown keywords because `$ref` and `$id` only apply inside schemas. Let's look at an example to see what I mean by this.

```
{
  "$id": "http://example.com/foo",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "aaa": {
      "const": { "$ref": "#/definitions/bbb" }
    },
    "bbb": { "$ref": "#/definitions/bbb" }
  },
  "ccc": { "$ref": "#/definitions/bbb" },
  "definitions": {
    "bbb": { "type": "string" }
  }
}
```

- The document as a whole is a schema, so `/$id` is understood by JSON Schema.
- The `properties` keyword is defined as an object whose values are schemas. Therefore, the value at `/properties/bbb` is a schema and `/properties/bbb/$ref` is understood by JSON Schema.
- The value of the `const` keyword is unconstrained. The value at `/properties/aaa/const` may look like a schema, but it's just a plain JSON object. Therefore `/properties/aaa/const/$ref` is not understood by JSON Schema.
- The value at `/ccc` is not a JSON Schema keyword, so it's value is not constrained and not a schema. Therefore, the `$id` and `$ref` keywords are not understood by JSON Schema.

---

That's how it works now. When you go back to older drafts (draft-05 iirc), it's a little different. Before then, `$ref` was defined in a separate specification called JSON Reference. JSON Schema extended JSON Reference. Therefore, the semantics of `$ref` applied everywhere it appeared in a JSON Schema.

**EDIT:**

> What happens when a `$ref` inside a known keyword references a schema deep inside an unknown keyword. for example, what if `#/properties/bbb` referenced `#/ccc`?

That's a really good question. Referencing `#/ccc` should be an error because `#/ccc` is not a schema and `$ref` only allows you to reference a schema.

Comment: wow.  answered at the same time, says the same thing, yet yours is somehow better. ;-)

Comment: @jason-desrosiers when you say `$refs are not resolved within unknown keywords because $ref and $id only apply inside schemas.` What happens when a `$ref` inside  a known keyword references a schema deep inside an unknown keyword. for example, what if `#/properties/bbb` referenced `#/ccc`.

Comment: I kinda jumped the gun and posted this in two places, can you please take a look at my comment here: https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/687#issuecomment-443489995

Comment: @AravindanVe, I edited the answer to answer your question.

Comment: Oh thanks! That answers by question. But there is also the case of the tests. i.e. JSON-Schema-Test-Suite defines many test cases that routinely reference unknown parts of the schema, like in the first example.

Comment: I think the test suite is wrong. I don't think the spec authors recognized this problem when they added the restriction that you can only reference schemas. I certainly haven't thought about this case til you brought it up.

Answer (score 1):

I just saw your question on the JSON Schema site in an issue.  I'll post here what I posted there as well.  However, also look at the edit.

---

> Which of the following is the `$ref` at `#/tilda~0field/slash~1field/$id/$ref` resolved to?

I think [Section 8.2](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.8.2) gives the answer: "A subschema's "$id" is resolved against the base URI of its parent schema."  This means that it will be http://example.com/t/test/document.json.

> Which of the `$id`s in `#/tilda~0field` must be considered as baseURI for the `$ref` in question and why.

The base URI for this is the `$id` at the root, re-routed by the `$id` in `tilda~field`.

1. Start with `http://example.com/root.json`.
2. Change folders to `t` and use file `inner.json`.
3. Change folders to `test` (inside `t`) and use file `document.json`.

---

**EDIT**

Having a look at @customcommander's reply and realizing that the value in `tilde~field` isn't processed as a schema, I'd like to say that the `#ref` wouldn't be processed at all.  It's just a plain JSON string with no inherent meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your second schema is valid though?

For example according to the [JSON Schema Core specification](https://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#rfc.section.8.2), the `$id` property should be a string

> If present, the value for this keyword MUST be a string

Therefore the following looks wrong to me:

```
"slash/field": {
  "$id": {
      "$id": "test/b",
      "$ref": "document.json"
  }
}
```

Then I think that your first `$ref` isn't correct either:

```
"attributes": {
  "$ref": "#/tilda~0field/slash~1field/$id"
}
```

It should probably read:

```
"attributes": {
  "$ref": "#/tilda~0field/slash~1field"
}
```

The same specification document also says this about `$id` and `$ref`:
*Cf [this example](https://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#idExamples)*

> The "$id" keyword defines a URI for the schema, and the base URI that other URI references within the schema are resolved against.

Or as [Ajv](https://ajv.js.org/#ref) simply puts it:

> $ref is resolved as the uri-reference using schema $id as the base URI […].

Given the current state of your schema, I can only approximate the answer to your question but the ref would probably resolve to something like `t/inner.json#document.json`

Comment: The `$id` property of `slash/field` as an object is fine since `tilde~field` isn't a recognized keyword.  The spec says to treat such things as miscellaneous data and ignore it.  Thus references into the JSON structure here *could* work normally.